# OpenCL hang on cl::Context destruction

Tags: c++, callback, opencl

I have the following object:

```
class Manager
{
   cl::context m_context;
   cl::CommandQueue m_queue
   // ... more stuff obviously.

public:
   ~Manager() { 
       m_queue.finish();
       m_queue = nullptr;
       m_context = nullptr; 
   }
};
```

This works fine. But when I add some DestructorCallback over my `cl::Buffer`s, the program hang on the release of the `cl::context`.

```
cl::int err;
auto buffer = cl::Buffer(manager->GetContext(), CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 1000, NULL, &err);
char* ptr = new char[10];
ptr[0] = 'a';
buffer.setDestructorCallback(Utils::Function::setDestroyBufferCallback, (void*)(ptr));
```

And the callback function looks like this:

```
void Utils::Function::setDestroyBufferCallback(cl_mem buffer, void* data)
{   
    std::cout << "Destroy cl::Buffer with name: " << std::string(data) << std::endl;
    delete data;
}
```

I don't understand, I properlly delete all the buffer prior to get to this point, but still.

The same application without DestructionCallback works well, but with it, its freeze (in debug) on close.

Comment: Maybe create [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like you've got undefined behaviour/a memory overwrite elsewhere in your program and the OpenCL context is just the random but mostly deterministic victim. If you're using a compiler that can insert instrumentation for memory and other UB errors (such as ASan and UBSan in clang), or if you can use `valgrind` or similar, this is probably a good time to try out those options.

Comment: This has been a long run, I was force to work on a different project, but back on track. This issue seems to occur only on Windows version and not on Linux. I ran UBSan and valgrind on the linux version, and nothing seems to happen. The problem is now occuring over the command queue, and it returns a Access violation read using a Nvidia context, it returned a pure virtual call error when using intel context, and no error when using oclgrind for context... I suspect something wrong with the dll. This only occurs when Im closing my application at the end­.